# ConTeXt: Adding a page border with two lines

Tags: context, frame, context-lmtx

Recently I've tried to add a simple double page border to a document in ConTeXt (with mtx-context version: 2023.09.26 18:19). E.g. more formal cover pages or documents might use something like that.

[image]

With LaTeX I would have used `eso-pic` or just added a `tikzpicture` drawing a rectangle.
Now using ConTeXt. With a single line I would have used `\framed` as shown on https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Framed. But now given an offset and two lines to draw.
I started to draw the rectangles in MetaPost in `\startuseMPgraphic` using `unitsquare` and shifting them.

Are there other (maybe easier) options to do this in ConTeXt?

My minimal example:

```
\mainlanguage[de]
\language[de]
\enableregime[utf]

\setuppapersize[A4][A4]
\setuplayout[topspace=24mm,
    backspace=24mm,
    header=0pt,
    footer=0pt,
    height=middle,
    width=middle]

\setuppagenumbering[location=]
\setupbodyfont [12pt]

\startuseMPgraphic{pagebackground}
StartPage ;
path outerPath, innerPath;
numeric offset, margin, w, h;
offset := 10mm;
margin := 1mm;
w := OverlayWidth;
h := OverlayHeight;

outerPath := unitsquare xysized (w - 2*offset, h - 2*offset);
outerPath := outerPath shifted (offset, offset);
innerPath := unitsquare xysized (w - 2*offset - 2*margin, h - 2*offset - 2*margin);
innerPath := innerPath shifted (offset + margin, offset + margin);

draw outerPath withpen pencircle scaled 2pt withcolor red;
draw innerPath withpen pencircle scaled 1pt withcolor red;
StopPage ;
\stopuseMPgraphic

\defineoverlay
[pagebackground]
[\useMPgraphic{pagebackground}]

\setupbackgrounds
[page]
[background=pagebackground]

\starttext
\setupinterlinespace[medium]
\hfill
\blank[big]
\startalignment[middle]
{\tfc\bfb Acme Award}\crlf
{\it Founded 1970}\crlf
\blank[big]
\stopalignment
\input tufte
\stoptext
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can apply the background to the text area and use `OverlayBox` which has the size of the text block, with `enlarged` you set the offset for the border.

```
\startuseMPgraphic{pageborder}
  draw OverlayBox enlarged 10mm withpen pencircle scaled 1pt withcolor "red";
  draw OverlayBox enlarged 11mm withpen pencircle scaled 2pt withcolor "red";
\stopuseMPgraphic

\defineoverlay
  [pageborder]
  [\useMPgraphic{pageborder}]

\setupbackgrounds
  [text]
  [text]
  [background=pageborder]

\setuplayout
  [tight]
  [   topspace=24mm,
    backspace=24mm,
      cutspace=24mm,
  bottomspace=24mm]

\setuplayout
  [tight]

\setupinterlinespace
  [medium]

\starttext

\blank[force,big]

\startalignment[middle]
  {\bfb Acme Award}\crlf
  {\it Founded 1970}
\stopalignment

\blank[2*big]

\input tufte

\stoptext
```